Relative entropy of entanglement
In the formula for the relative entropy of entanglement, one has:
\begin{eqnarray}
E_R(\rho)=\text{min}_{\sigma\in S}\text{Tr}\left(\rho\log\rho - \rho\log \sigma\right)
\end{eqnarray}
where $\rho$ is the quantum state of interest, and the minimization is carried out over all states $\sigma\in S$, where $S$ is the set of separable states.
If $\sigma$ is bipartite separable, we can always write it as:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma=\sum_j p_j \Phi_j\otimes\Psi_j,
\end{eqnarray}
with both $\Phi_j,\Psi_j$ representing density matrices of pure states. Suppose now that one deals with a state $\rho$ such that the second term in $E_R(\rho)$ has the form:
\begin{eqnarray}
c\text{Tr}(\log(\sigma)),
\end{eqnarray}
for some prefactor $c$. Since $\sigma$ is separable, is there an easy way to obtain the matrix logarithm of $\sigma$? How could one proceed on solving the minimization problem in that case?

$c\log(\sigma)$ is a matrix but $E_R(\rho)$ is a scalar. It's not clear what it means for $E_R(\rho)$ to "have the form" $c\log(\sigma)$.

Thanks for pointing that out, it is corrected now.

I'm afraid being separable doesn't help with computing the logarithm. Having the form you mentioned does make the optimization easier, as it makes it a separable spectral function, but it's not necessary to exploit that, as the general problem can be solved directly.
This is a rather recent development on optimizing the relative entropy: since a few years ago we have an algorithm that can handle it (Skajaa-Ye), and since a few months a solver that implements it (Hypatia).
As for optimizing the relative entropy of entanglement directly, I added a function to the quantum information library Ket implementing it. Just call entanglement_entropy. It uses the DPS hierarchy to optimize over the set of separable states.
Note, however, that it will only work well for full-rank states. If you need it to work for non-full-rank states as well, it is straightforward (but a lot of work) to do that using the techniques in arXiv:2407.00152 and arXiv:2407.00241.
